# jsp:UseBean vs. Struts <bean> tag

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, javabeans

I am learning about Struts2 and it's not completely clear to me how and when to use the tag `<jsp:UseBean>` vs the Struts bean:... tag.

I found an article outlining the differences but them but there is not any example provided.

```
http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/struts-taglib/tlddoc/bean/define.html
```

The `<bean:define>` tag differs from `<jsp:useBean>` in several ways, including:

- Unconditionally creates (or replaces) a bean under the specified
  identifier.
- Can create a bean with the value returned by a property
  getter of a different bean (including properties referenced with a
  nested and/or indexed property name).
- Can create a bean whose
  contents is a literal string (or the result of a runtime expression)
  specified by the value attribute.
- Does not support nested content
  (such as jsp:setProperty tags) that are only executed if a bean was
  actually created.

Here's my quick test code that uses the UseBean tag. Could anyone please give me an example how/why (or if) I should use the Struts bean:... tag(s) in the display.jsp instead?

**`index.jsp`:**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form name="input" action="TestServlet" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="txtFirstName" placeholder="First Name">
            <input type="text" name="txtLastName" placeholder="Last Name">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**`TestServlet.java`:**

```
    package com.website.servlets;

    import java.io.IOException;

    import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import com.website.models.Person;

    /**
     * Servlet implementation class TestServlet
     */
    @WebServlet("/TestServlet")
    public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
           
        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
         */
        public TestServlet() {
            super();
        }


        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            
            String fname = request.getParameter("txtFirstName");
            String lname = request.getParameter("txtLastName");
            
            Person p = new Person();        
            
            p.setFirstName(fname);
            p.setLastName(lname);
            
            request.setAttribute("myPersonObj", p);
            
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("display.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);      
        }

    }
```

**`display.jsp`:**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
                    
        <jsp:useBean id="myPersonObj" class="com.website.models.Person" scope="request"></jsp:useBean>
        
        <p> 
            Full Name : <jsp:getProperty property="firstName" name="myPersonObj"/>
                        <jsp:getProperty property="lastName" name="myPersonObj"/>
        </p>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your question is tagged struts2, your question is about a struts1 tag, and you don't seem to be using struts (neither 1 or 2). Start by deciding if you want to use Struts. Struts 1 is completely obsolete. So if you choose to use struts, choose the struts2 version, and look at the struts2 documentation, not the struts1 documentation. Note that jsp:useBean is completely obsolete as well. Learn the JSP EL and the JSTL.

Comment: I would think you should create the bean in the *servlet*, and either put it in a session attribute or pass it to the JSP in a request attribute (which is what your servlet code is actually doing!), and not use any bean tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are actually creating the bean in the servlet, and putting it in a request attribute, you can replace:

```
    <jsp:useBean id="myPersonObj" class="com.website.models.Person" scope="request"></jsp:useBean>

    <p> 
        Full Name : <jsp:getProperty property="firstName" name="myPersonObj"/>
                    <jsp:getProperty property="lastName" name="myPersonObj"/>
    </p>
```

With (using EL):

```
    <p> 
        Full Name : ${myPersonObj.firstName}
                    ${myPersonObj.lastName}
    </p>
```

See the [Servlets info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) here on SO:

> Do NOT use `<jsp:useBean>` if you're already using a servlet to process the model. It will only lead to confusion and maintenance trouble because the `<jsp:useBean>` follows a different level of MVC approach than when you're using servlets. It's either servlets or `<jsp:useBean>`, not both.

Because `<jsp:useBean>` is not compatible with servlets, and you need to use servlets to do any decent coding, `<jsp:useBean>` is "completely obsolete" (as JB Nizet put it in the first comment).

Answer (score 1):

You should use struts2 tags, they has support for OGNL. OGNL has a context and a value stack which is a root object. So, your request scoped object is displayed as

```
<p> 
    Full Name : <s:property value="#request.myPersonObj.firstName"/>&nbsp;
                <s:property value="#request.myPersonObj.lastName"/>
</p>
```

For better understanding OGNL concepts see [docs](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/ognl.html).