# Accessing Bean set in one JSP in another JSP

Tags: java, jsp

The following is the code i'm using.

1: LoginPage.jsp

```
    <jsp:useBean id="checkBean" class="NewPack.Member" scope="request" />
    <jsp:setProperty name="checkBean" property="username"    value="checkProp" /> 
    <form name="login" method="post"  action="webpages/Result.jsp" scope="request">
        username:<input type="text" name="username">
        <br/>
        password:<input type="password" name="password" >            
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="login">            
    </form>
```

2: Result.jsp

```
<jsp:useBean id="checkBean" class="NewPack.Member" scope="request" />        
${checkBean.username}
```

3: NewPack.Member is a simple java bean with two properties
   **String username,password**
   and the corresponding setters and getters.

I'm setting the bean before the form element and in the request scope in LoginPage.jsp however while accessing it in Result.jsp I am not getting the values of the set property.

PS: form has been included deliberately so as to pass the control to Result.jsp. The form inputs will be used to conduct further validations which are not connected to the Member bean.

Comment: Don't use jsp:useBean. its obsolete. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548524/hoe-to-jspusebean-setproperty-to-two-different-bean-having-same-property-name/28551251#28551251 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454699/jspusebean-vs-struts-bean-tag/25454826#25454826 for two ways to do it without jsp:useBean

Comment: I can very well do it without using jsp:bean but I am actually perturbed as to why is this not working ? What is wrong with this code (because it quite clearly is wrong otherwise it would have worked)

Answer (score 0):

Do the follwing change in your Result.jsp and check :-

```
<jsp:useBean id="checkBean" class="NewPack.Member" scope="request" /> 
<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="checkBean"/>        
${checkBean.username}
```

Comment: I don't think it'll work cause the bean i'm setting has no relation with the form input fields. This would simply result in a null object, which is precisely what I am stuck with now.